# Can I save all the emails in one particular Gmail folder onto a disc/stick etc?

Tags: gmail

Can I save all the emails in one particular Gmail folder onto a disc/stick etc?

Answer (score 2):

To download your gmail messages you'll need to hook up a POP Email program (Thunderbird, Mail on Mac, Outlook as some examples).

Make sure you set the account type to POP. Then follow the instructions posted [here](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13289)

For posterity here's the instructions from the source above:

> 1. Sign in to Gmail.
> 2. Click the gear icon  in the upper right, then select Settings.
> 3. Click Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
> 4. Select Enable POP1 for all mail.
> 5. Choose the action you'd like your Gmail messages to take after they are accessed with POP.
> 6. Click Save Changes.
> 7. Configure your POP client.
>
>    - All messages may be downloaded to another computer once; after downloading mail, it will not download again.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using IMAP? Just curious.

Comment: There really isn't, but you have to be sure your email program is set to download and store those emails in that case. I think Thunderbird does this by default for IMAP connections.